# How to hook to routes resolver?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I hook to MVC routes resolver? I need to log the urls that MVC tries to resolve to find out why it fails on production server.

Custom controller factory won't work, because the route that fails is a route to a WCF service embedded in the MVC application - it doesn't even hit the controller factory.

I need something as pure as possible, without any filters whatsoever.

Comment: Have you tried ELMAH?

Answer (score 0):

I personally like using [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/). It provides me with a view of what is going on in my app.

The portion you would be interested in is [route debugging](http://getglimpse.com/Help/Routes-Tab). In it, you can see all of the routes and the parameters that are passed in. You can also see if routes match each of the constraints.

Glimpse has extensible authorization that allows you to determine who and when the information is displayed to the user.